# Cocoa: Mount SMB folder with FSMountServerVolumeSync

Tags: cocoa, volume, mount

Could someone post a snippet on the correct syntax for using this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/145964-solved-trouble-with-fsmountservervolumesync.html